# How to update MongoDB with no duplicates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using Meteor framework with Blaze. How can I fetch data from an API and only insert new data in my MongoDB collection and not duplicates?

1. Fetching data from the API.

   ```
   if (Meteor.isServer) {
       Meteor.methods({
           fetchApiData: function () {
               this.unblock();
               return Meteor.http.call('GET','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');},
   ```
2. Insert data into database:

   ```
   populateDatabaseApi: function () {
     Meteor.call('fetchApiData', function(error, result) {
       myCollection.insert({
         //upsert: true,
         A: result.data.title,
         B: result.data.userId,
         C: result.data.id });
     });
   },
   ```

When using "myCollection.update" with "upsert: true" it does not insert new entries obviously. What is best practice to go about checking the API for data and inserting ONLY new entries with no duplicates and updating existing entries?

Thank you.

Comment: If you need to guarantee uniqueness, you should place the appropriate unique indices in the DB as well, anything you do in meteor can potentially fail without them.

Comment: Why not just do it the simple way with [Collection.upsert()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert) ?

Answer (score 1):

here's how i handle what i call reference data at startup. it's driven off of JSON data. you have to pick a field that serves as your "reference" for each JSON object, so you can see if it's already in the db.

```
_.each(ItemData.items, function(q) {
    check(q, ItemsSchema);

    Items.upsert({
        item: q.item
    }, {
        $set: {
            item: q.item,
        }
    }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            let errMsg = 'Error while writing item data';
            console.error(errMsg, error);
            throw new Meteor.Error('500', errMsg);
        }
    });
});
```

i use an upsert to handle insert vs update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your specific framework, so I can't help with syntax, but you should be able to find all documents with the *same* properties as the document you're trying to insert (there should be only one). If there is one, then save it using `upsert`. If there isn't, then the object you're saving is unique, and you should save a new one.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. Do i have to compare something like the title with existing entries in the database?

Comment: If `title` is a unique field within the collection, then yes you could simply compare the title (or any other single unique field, or two fields that together make the document unique). However, if there are no unique fields, then you must ask the database if there is an entire document that is equal to the one you're trying to save (sans `id`, `__v`, etc fields that are automatically generated)

Answer (score 0):

Using only "vanilla" Meteor, assuming your api object have unique ids and that you have the proper data access (ie, if item exist findOne would find it), I'd use :

```
populateDatabaseApi: function () {
      Meteor.call('fetchApiData', function(error, result) {
        var item = myCollection.findOne({A : result.data.id})
        if(item){
           //do nothing, this item already is in the db
        }else{
           myCollection.insert({
             A: result.data.title,
             B: result.data.userId,
             C: result.data.id });
           });
        }
    },
```